# composer not parsing composer.json

Tags: php, json, symfony, composer-php

i have created a bundle. in bundle i am creating two tables in database. this is following my composer.json.

```
{
    "name": "xxxx/xxx-designer",
    "description": "XXXX",
    "license": "MIT",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/giturl",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "xxxx",
            "email": "xxxx@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Acme\\Bundle\\DemoBundle\\Composer\\AcmeHandler::InstallTabs"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Acme\\Bundle\\DemoBundle\\Composer\\AcmeHandler::InstallTabs"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0.x-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Now problem is this when i perform `php composer.phar update` then composer not execute post-update-cmd or post-install-cmd but if add following line into main composer.json

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Acme\\Bundle\\DemoBundle\\Composer\\AcmeHandler::InstallTabs"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Acme\\Bundle\\DemoBundle\\Composer\\AcmeHandler::InstallTabs"
    ]
},
```

then `php composer.phar update` execute this command and my tables will be created i am wondering why composer not execute commands from my bundle's composer.json. please help why composer not execute script from bundle's composer.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#what-is-a-script-)

```
  Note: Only scripts defined in the root package's composer.json are executed.
  If a dependency of the root package specifies its own scripts, Composer does not
  execute those additional scripts.
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can not do that with a vendor post-instal/update-scripts.

**BUT**

See how it is resolved in BraincraftedBootstrapBundle:

[They have a separate command to copy the icons](https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle/blob/develop/Command/InstallCommand.php)

I show that it can be added to composer.json.
[BraincraftedBootstrapBundle -> Installing Glyphicons](http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/getting-started.html#installing-glyphicons)